# How to specify time zone for Java's GC log?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I've configured my JVM to write Garbage Collection stats to a log file, with options like:

`-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=1 -XX:GCLogFileSize=64M`

The problem is, my application's server log uses UTC for log messages, but the GC log uses the server time zone, which is currently 4 hours behind UTC. This makes it a little harder to reconcile events in my server log with GC pauses.

Is there any way to configure which time zone the Java GC log uses?

I'm on Java 7.

Comment: Can you set the JVM's default timezone to UTC-4? (No idea if this is what the GC log uses!)

Comment: The JVM's default timezone is already UTC-4, which is what the GC log uses. My problem is that I've configured my server log to write log messages with UTC timestamps, so they don't match the timestamps in the GC log. I could of course change my server log's timezone to UTC-4, but I was wondering if it's possible to change the GC log's timezone.

Comment: Oh, right, I see. What about piping one log or other through something which would extract and shift the timestamps? (Not exactly elegant...)

Comment: Yeah that's a workaround (in case the answer to this question is "no, not possible"), but if I'm going to do that I might as well just change the timezone (temporarily) that our server log uses, to match the GC log's timezone. At least that's just one line of config.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux you can set `TZ` variable to `UTC`.
E.g.

```
TZ=UTC java -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:gc.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=1 -XX:GCLogFileSize=64M SomeClass
```

Or globally (or in a script, that starts your application):

```
export TZ=UTC
```

This will modify the timestamps of java GC log.

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted it. This is exactly what I was looking for.